# The default blue highlight removal for select control not working in high contrast mode in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I removed the default blue highlight for a select control using the following code:

```
.ps_select:focus::-ms-value {
 /* For IE10 and above to remove blue hightlight */
 background-color: inherit;  
 }
```

Though this works in normal mode, it doesn't in high contrast. You'll see that there is a purple background on focus of the select control. This  implies that in high contrast mode the blue color is still used and the contrasting makes it purple.

Is there a solution for this? Or is this a bug?

I am using IE11

Comment: Isn't this just something set in Windows, rather than the browser? I mean, high contrast already overrules all other CSS- and design-rules, so probably also the select-background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {  
/* Remove purple highlight in HC mode */  
.ps_select:focus::-ms-value{
  background-color: transparent;  /*make the select background transparent in ie */
  color: white;
 }
}
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
/* Remove blue highlight in Normal mode*/  
.ps_select:focus::-ms-value{
  background-color: transparent;  
  color: black;
}
}
```

Comment: In fact, I am not sure how this works, because the meaning of active and  none are actually different from what I thought it was. But it works. :)